# Going through first tutorial: 'cannot access native cert store' when starting the node

Tags: substrate, polkadot

I've tried to initiate my first instance of the substrate node using the [Create Your First Substrate Chain](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain) tutorial.

On running the command

`./target/release/node-template --dev --tmp`

We got a panic

```
main WARN sc_cli::commands::run_cmd  Running in --dev mode, RPC CORS has been disabled.
2020-09-01 11:32:26.633 main INFO sc_cli::runner  Substrate Node
2020-09-01 11:32:26.633 main INFO sc_cli::runner  ✌️  version 2.0.0-rc6-c9fda53-x86_64-macos
2020-09-01 11:32:26.633 main INFO sc_cli::runner  ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2020
2020-09-01 11:32:26.633 main INFO sc_cli::runner   Chain specification: Development
2020-09-01 11:32:26.633 main INFO sc_cli::runner    Node name: yummy-increase-5727
2020-09-01 11:32:26.633 main INFO sc_cli::runner   Role: AUTHORITY
2020-09-01 11:32:26.633 main INFO sc_cli::runner   Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/k4/8vkq36gd4dv2npf7pzfpt9mm0000gn/T/substrateuBAgDv/chains/dev/db
2020-09-01 11:32:26.633 main INFO sc_cli::runner  ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-1 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)
2020-09-01 11:32:26.699 main INFO sc_service::client::client   Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xa2b5…3bab, header-hash: 0x0bea…49e8)
2020-09-01 11:32:26.700 main INFO afg   Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.
2020-09-01 11:32:26.725 main INFO sc_consensus_slots  ⏱  Loaded block-time = 6000 milliseconds from genesis on first-launch
2020-09-01 11:32:26.726 main WARN sc_service::builder  Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
2020-09-01 11:32:26.726 main INFO sub-libp2p    Local node identity is: 12D3KooWMZTpWokAWBBuKTuv3EuUpf4f8PnctCgsCCs46tzMZ1ZN (legacy representation: QmSVUxS4iwXroNRbqs9zNGDsJhskXsc66c7CapZWVjjyht)

====================

Version: 2.0.0-rc6-c9fda53-x86_64-macos

   0: backtrace::backtrace::trace
   1: backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new
   2: sp_panic_handler::set::{{closure}}
   3: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
   4: _rust_begin_unwind
   5: core::panicking::panic_fmt
   6: core::option::expect_none_failed
   7: hyper_rustls::connector::HttpsConnector<hyper::client::connect::http::HttpConnector>::new
   8: sc_offchain::api::http::SharedClient::new
   9: sc_offchain::OffchainWorkers<Client,Storage,Block>::new
  10: sc_service::builder::build_offchain_workers
  11: node_template::service::new_full
  12: sc_cli::runner::Runner<C>::run_node_until_exit
  13: node_template::command::run
  14: node_template::main
  15: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
  16: std::rt::lang_start_internal
  17: _main


Thread 'main' panicked at 'cannot access native cert store: Custom { kind: Other, error: Error { code: -25262, message: "The Trust Settings Record was corrupted." } }', /Users/rmp/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/hyper-rustls-0.21.0/src/connector.rs:46

This is a bug. Please report it at:

    support.anonymous.an
```

Any ideas? It's a pretty basic tutorial and not a lot to get wrong.

Running on Mac 10.14.6, Node 12.18.3, Yarn 1.22.5

**Edit:**
Looking back at the compile I did notice that I'd already had rust / rustup installed and the compile through a warning that it ignored. Possibly related?

**Additional logging:**

```
RUST_LOG=debug RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./target/release/node-template -lruntime=debug --dev --tmp
2020-09-02 06:00:57.058 main WARN sc_cli::commands::run_cmd  Running in --dev mode, RPC CORS has been disabled.
2020-09-02 06:00:57.058 main INFO sc_cli::runner  Substrate Node
2020-09-02 06:00:57.058 main INFO sc_cli::runner  ✌️  version 2.0.0-rc6-c9fda53-x86_64-macos
2020-09-02 06:00:57.058 main INFO sc_cli::runner  ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2020
2020-09-02 06:00:57.058 main INFO sc_cli::runner   Chain specification: Development
2020-09-02 06:00:57.058 main INFO sc_cli::runner    Node name: educated-tub-7928
2020-09-02 06:00:57.058 main INFO sc_cli::runner   Role: AUTHORITY
2020-09-02 06:00:57.058 main INFO sc_cli::runner   Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/k4/8vkq36gd4dv2npf7pzfpt9mm0000gn/T/substratelHH2Ba/chains/dev/db
2020-09-02 06:00:57.058 main INFO sc_cli::runner  ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-1 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)
2020-09-02 06:00:57.132 main INFO sc_service::client::client   Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xa2b5…3bab, header-hash: 0x0bea…49e8)
2020-09-02 06:00:57.132 main DEBUG db  DB Commit 0x0beaa5a0e87b3bd60a9e16630bcd9c27544a4d9f7b8bfb7e39d6f432eac049e8 (0), best = true
2020-09-02 06:00:57.134 main INFO afg   Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.
2020-09-02 06:00:57.154 main DEBUG wasm-runtime  Prepared new runtime version Some(RuntimeVersion { spec_name: RuntimeString::Owned("node-template"), impl_name: RuntimeString::Owned("node-template"), authoring_version: 1, spec_version: 1, impl_version: 1, apis: [([223, 106, 203, 104, 153, 7, 96, 155], 3), ([55, 227, 151, 252, 124, 145, 245, 228], 1), ([64, 254, 58, 212, 1, 248, 149, 154], 4), ([210, 188, 152, 151, 238, 208, 143, 21], 2), ([247, 139, 39, 139, 229, 63, 69, 76], 2), ([221, 113, 141, 92, 197, 50, 98, 212], 1), ([171, 60, 5, 114, 41, 31, 235, 139], 1), ([237, 153, 197, 172, 178, 94, 237, 245], 2), ([188, 157, 137, 144, 79, 91, 146, 63], 1), ([55, 200, 187, 19, 80, 169, 162, 168], 1)], transaction_version: 1 }) in 20 ms.
2020-09-02 06:00:57.155 main DEBUG wasm-runtime  Allocated WASM instance 1/8
2020-09-02 06:00:57.158 main INFO sc_consensus_slots  ⏱  Loaded block-time = 6000 milliseconds from genesis on first-launch
2020-09-02 06:00:57.158 main WARN sc_service::builder  Using default protocol ID "sup" because none is configured in the chain specs
2020-09-02 06:00:57.158 main INFO sub-libp2p    Local node identity is: 12D3KooWHX7yTCJP8wZn53w98pnvJ76HuHvYrNLhCmJbnkbx4ew1 (legacy representation: QmUVjga4dsGvTZJfxisxLogR3fqPDLxbZTUgLhRgZBZJdS)
2020-09-02 06:00:57.160 main DEBUG libp2p_websocket::framed  /ip6/::/tcp/30333 is not a websocket multiaddr
2020-09-02 06:00:57.161 main DEBUG libp2p_websocket::framed  /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333 is not a websocket multiaddr

====================

Version: 2.0.0-rc6-c9fda53-x86_64-macos

   0: backtrace::backtrace::trace
   1: backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new
   2: sp_panic_handler::set::{{closure}}
   3: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
   4: _rust_begin_unwind
   5: core::panicking::panic_fmt
   6: core::option::expect_none_failed
   7: hyper_rustls::connector::HttpsConnector<hyper::client::connect::http::HttpConnector>::new
   8: sc_offchain::api::http::SharedClient::new
   9: sc_offchain::OffchainWorkers<Client,Storage,Block>::new
  10: sc_service::builder::build_offchain_workers
  11: node_template::service::new_full
  12: sc_cli::runner::Runner<C>::run_node_until_exit
  13: node_template::command::run
  14: node_template::main
  15: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
  16: std::rt::lang_start_internal
  17: _main


Thread 'main' panicked at 'cannot access native cert store: Custom { kind: Other, error: Error { code: -25262, message: "The Trust Settings Record was corrupted." } }', /Users/rmp/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/hyper-rustls-0.21.0/src/connector.rs:46
```

Comment: Did you run ./scripts/init.sh in the node-template folder before running --dev? That should update your rust and everything related to it.

Comment: I did not. I ran it now and everything was up to date. Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately the same thread panicked.

Comment: Can you try running with more logging? `RUST_LOG=debug RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./target/release/node-template -lruntime=debug --dev --tmp`

Comment: Possibly related https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/5442

Comment: Thanks Dan. Appreciate the tutorial and help. I added extra logging.

I'm also wondering if the rust I have installed already could be incompatible.

Comment: Are you using macOS? If so, what version?

Comment: I am using Mac. Mojave 10.14.6. Unable to install higher without breaking other software.

I did completely uninstall Rust with `rustup.sh --uninstall' and 'rustc --uninstall' and downloaded and installed the latest.

Recompiled substrate-node-template without any rust warnings this time. Still produced the same panic.

Comment: @DanForbes Is the github a better place to try to resolve an issue like this? In the error it says 'This is a bug. Please report it at: **support.anonymous.an**' I'm not sure what that means as it's not a website.

Comment: Personally speaking, I will probably respond more quickly to GitHub Issues. It's possible that the version of Mac you're using is just not compatible with Substrate :/ https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/5442#issuecomment-646375398

Comment: That would be a shame. A lot of us pro mac users don't upgrade sometimes years after new releases are out. I will keep an eye on the github and maybe try getting a substrate node running in the future. Cheers